# How to reproduce the same state of random-based algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, random

I am working on algorithm which contain a random initial state. So the output of this algorithm is not robust in each time I run it. This causes a lot of headache for me while I catch a wrong output and want to debug it to see where the problem was because when I run it again, the problem may not re-produced due the random factor of the algorithm. I am using C++ random generator as follow:

```
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 rnd_generator(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> rnd_distribution(0, data_size - 1);

    auto get_random_index = [&](){
        return rnd_distribution(rnd_generator);
    };
```

How I can imitate the last random sequence generated by this function? For example, Can I give it some kind of static seed that I can re enter it and get the exactly same random sequence? I am asking because I think it is common problem so there may be some nice and efficient well-known way.

Comment: Don't use `random_device`, then. Seed the `mt19937` with a fixed seed.

Comment: You're not seeding your MT properly. You need to at least be using `std::seed_seq`. 4 bytes is not enough to seed MT's huge internal state.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

save the result of the call to `rd()` and use that to initialise `rnd_generator` on the next pass

example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>


auto main() -> int
{
    using namespace std;

    random_device rd;
    auto seed = rd();

    for (int pass = 0 ; pass < 3 ; ++pass)
    {
        mt19937 rnd_generator(seed);
        uniform_int_distribution<> rnd_distribution(0, 9);

        for (int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; ++i)
        {
            cout << rnd_distribution(rnd_generator) << ", ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

example output:

```
9, 5, 3, 5, 4,
9, 5, 3, 5, 4,
9, 5, 3, 5, 4,
```

Answer (score 3):

`std::mt19937 rnd_generator(rd());` seeds the PRNG each time with a different random seed.  If you want to have the same random sequence while you are testing then you can just hard code a seed instead of using `rd()`.

```
std::mt19937 rnd_generator(0);  // each run will use the seed value of 0
```

Comment: Thanks, the problem with this solution is if I test all my samples on the same seed, some problems may not occurs at all. Especially, when the sample set is small.

Comment: OP should probably be using `std::seed_seq` at least; even that is sub-optimal. MT has a huge internal state.

Comment: However, it may be the only solution so i have to set it as static then change it many times and test them all in each time

Comment: @HumamHelfawi You could run test with different hard coded seeds to make sure you are catching different cases

Comment: @NathanOliver yes that is

Comment: You can also print out your seed for each run, then you can reproduce only if you need it (i.e. an error occurred) or keep running. c.f. the answer from @Simple.

Answer (score 1):

You can print an RNG engine to a `std::ostream` to serialise it and then read it from a `std::istream` to deserialise it. Note that due to your use of `std::uniform_int_distribution<>`, you will not reproduce the same sequence of numbers when using different compilers.

Answer (score 0):

The `std::mt19937` is the source of your randomness. It makes sense to use a consitant seed (a `uint_least32_t` I think) for testing, but it's also fine to use `random_device()` (which is function that gives a 'random' `uint_least32_t`).

The problem is you're creating it in the wrong place. Design your code so that the interesting logic is seperate from random sources. Making providing randomness the caller's/class-creators problem is called [Dependency Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130794/what-is-dependency-injection) and makes code testable.

Something like this:

```
    class ThingDooer final
    {
        std::mt19937 _prng;
    public:
        // ThingDooer(uint_least32_t seed);
        // ThingDooer() : ThingDoor(std::_Random_device()) {}; // these two or
        ThingDooer(std::mt19937 prng);
        void DoThing();
    };
```

One of the first things I did in C++ ([It's terrible and reads like C#](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/83603/random-class-in-c)) was wrapping `std::mt19937` in an `IRandom`  interface so that I could provide mock implementations with exactly specified numbers. This might be overkill for you of course. Neverless, without dragging in a mocking libary, I'll still show an idea of what we might mock:

```
    class RandallRandom : public IRandom final
    {
    public:
        RandallRandom();
        int32_t Next() { return 4; }
    };
```